# jQuery how to convert string to number while submit?

Tags: jquery, string, numbers

I have a table with days of week. When I checked checkbox and clicked `add` button, it will show tr row like `Sunday,Thursday,Saturday`, but I want it looks like `0,4,6` after clicked `submit` button, how to convert it to number?

```js
var rowNum = 0;
var dateVals = [];

$('#add').click(function() {
  var dateVals = [];
  $('#Date :checked').each(function() {
    dateVals.push($(this).attr('name'));
  });
  rowNum++;

  var row = '<tr id="row' + rowNum + '" class="dateRows">' + '<td class="rowDays">' + dateVals + '</td>' + '</tr>';

  $(row).insertAfter($("#add"));
  $('#Date :checked').removeAttr('checked');
});


$('#submit').click(function() {
  var dataString = $('.dateRows').map(function() {
    var text = $(this).find('.rowDays').text();
    return text;
  }).get().join('_');
  alert(dataString);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <table id="Date">
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <th>Sun</th>
        <th>Mon</th>
        <th>Tue</th>
        <th>Wed</th>
        <th>Thu</th>
        <th>Fri</th>
        <th>Sat</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <input name="Sunday" type="checkbox" value="0">
        </td>
        <td>
          <input name="Monday" type="checkbox" value="1">
        </td>
        <td>
          <input name="Tuesday" type="checkbox" value="2">
        </td>
        <td>
          <input name="Wednesday" type="checkbox" value="3">
        </td>
        <td>
          <input name="Thursday" type="checkbox" value="4">
        </td>
        <td>
          <input name="Friday" type="checkbox" value="5">
        </td>
        <td>
          <input name="Saturday" type="checkbox" value="6">
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
</div>
<div>
  <button type="button" id="add">Add</button>
</div>
<br>
<div>
  <button type="submit" id="submit">Submit</button>
</div>
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mpgn04c0/)

Comment: `var data = dataString.split(',').map(function(e) {
        return $('[name="' + e + '"]').val();
    }).join(',');` [Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tusharj/mpgn04c0/1/)

Comment: Thx, but it will erase the other number if I add multiple rows.

Comment: Check [updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tusharj/mpgn04c0/2/)

Comment: Is it possible to show `0,1,6_1,2,3_4,5` if I add multiple rows?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it possible to show 0,1,6_1,2,3_4,5 if I add multiple rows?

As you want to replace the day name by it's number without changing the delimiter `_`, you can use regex here.

```
var data = dataString.replace(/([a-z]+)/ig, function(e) {
  return $('[name="' + e + '"]').val();
});
```

**Steps:**

1. Extract the day name from string
2. Get the value of the day by name by using the [attribute-value selector](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/) in jQuery
3. Replace the day name by it's value

[**Live Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/tusharj/2bw3L9n2/)

```js
var rowNum = 0;
var dateVals = [];

$('#add').click(function() {
  var dateVals = [];
  $('#Date :checked').each(function() {
    dateVals.push($(this).attr('name'));
  });
  rowNum++;

  var row = '<tr id="row' + rowNum + '" class="dateRows">' + '<td class="rowDays">' + dateVals + '</td>' + '</tr>';

  $(row).insertAfter($("#add"));
  $('#Date :checked').removeAttr('checked');
});


$('#submit').click(function() {
  var dataString = $('.dateRows').map(function() {
    return $(this).find('.rowDays').text();
  }).get().join('_');

  var data = dataString.replace(/([a-z]+)/ig, function(e) {
    return $('[name="' + e + '"]').val();
  });

  document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = data;
});
```

```css
#result {
  margin-top: 20px;
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <table id="Date">
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <th>Sun</th>
        <th>Mon</th>
        <th>Tue</th>
        <th>Wed</th>
        <th>Thu</th>
        <th>Fri</th>
        <th>Sat</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <input name="Sunday" type="checkbox" value="0">
        </td>
        <td>
          <input name="Monday" type="checkbox" value="1">
        </td>
        <td>
          <input name="Tuesday" type="checkbox" value="2">
        </td>
        <td>
          <input name="Wednesday" type="checkbox" value="3">
        </td>
        <td>
          <input name="Thursday" type="checkbox" value="4">
        </td>
        <td>
          <input name="Friday" type="checkbox" value="5">
        </td>
        <td>
          <input name="Saturday" type="checkbox" value="6">
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>

<div>
  <button type="button" id="add">Add</button>
</div>
<br>
<div>
  <button type="submit" id="submit">Submit</button>
</div>

<pre id="result"></pre>
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using

```
$('#Date :checked').each(function() {
    dateVals.push($(this).attr('name')); });
```

Use following

```
 $('#Date :checked').each(function () {
        dateVals.push($(this).val());
    });
```